# finding a match in two different arrays - javaScript

Tags: javascript, foreach

I am trying to write a conditional that will find if a recipe is for vegetarians.
If is not for vegetarians, I want to console log the recipe array along with a message (non-vegetarian).

I tried couple of things, two for loops, and now I am trying with a forEach and includes. the problem is that something is wrong with my logic, is not printing the non-vegetarian message, and also, I am printing the recipes 3 times. This was the only thing I could think of, since I have to have a loop for the vegetarian items as well.

I have a [bin](http://jsbin.com/puzocanufi/edit?js,console) here. is a bit of a mess.

```js
var cookbook = [noodlesWithChicken, bakedPotatoWithBroccoli, hamPineapplePitaPizza, shrimpOliveSalad, chocolateBananaSundae];

var noodlesWithChicken = ["noodles", "chicken", "carrots", "cucumber", "peanut butter", "soy sauce" ];

var bakedPotatoWithBroccoli = ["russet potatos", "broccolli", "butter", "salt", "sour cream"];

var hamPineapplePitaPizza = ["pitas", "mozzarella", "pineaples", "ham"];

var shrimpOliveSalad = ["shrimp", "lettuce", "tomatoes", "artichoke", "black olives", "mayo", "chili sauce"];

var chocolateBananaSundae = ["bananas", "vanilla ice cream", "chocolate sauce", "shredded coconut"];


var vegetarians = ["chicken", "ham", "shrimp"];
var veganItems = ["chicken", "ham", "shrimp", "mozzarella", "sour cream", "mayo", "vanilla ice cream"];

cookbook.forEach(function(item){
  for(var i = 0; i < vegetarians.length; i++){
    if(cookbook.includes(vegetarians[i])){
      console.log(item + " (non-vegetarian)");
    } else {
      console.log(item);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: (Unrelated, but I'd consider renaming the vegetarian/vegan item lists--they're not veganItems, they're items *"prohibited"* to vegans.)

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine (not the loop), the issue is that you declare all the 'cookbooks' AFTER the array that contains them:

All I did was move the array down, right before you start looping, and I changed the loop a bit too... the way you have it now doesnt quite work:

```
cookbook.forEach(function(book){
  console.log(book);
  vegetarians.forEach(function(veg) {
    if (book.indexOf(veg) > -1) {
      console.log('contains meat');
    }
  });
});
```

Check out this new Bin: http://jsbin.com/bimafo/2/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0):

It is not printing the message because you are doing `cookbook.includes(vegetarians[i])` instead of `item.includes(vegetarians[i])`. It is the `item` that you want to check contains the non-vegetarian option.

You loop 3 times inside the `forEach`, once for each non-vegetarian option. This is why is is outputting 3 times per `item`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you need to declare your `cookbook` array after declaring its children.

I'd also like to point out that your for loop is calling `cookbook.includes` when you probably want to be calling `item.includes`.

Additionally, you're logging a result for every combination of a recipe and an item in the list of meats, when what you probably want to do is log once per recipe if any of the meats are in the recipe. You can easily do so with something like this:

```
cookbook.forEach(function(item){
  var hasMeat = vegetarians.some(item.includes.bind(item));
  console.log(item, hasMeat ? "is not vegetarian" : "is vegetarian");
});
```

```js
var noodlesWithChicken = ["noodles", "chicken", "carrots", "cucumber", "peanut butter", "soy sauce" ];

var bakedPotatoWithBroccoli = ["russet potatos", "broccolli", "butter", "salt", "sour cream"];

var hamPineapplePitaPizza = ["pitas", "mozzarella", "pineaples", "ham"];

var shrimpOliveSalad = ["shrimp", "lettuce", "tomatoes", "artichoke", "black olives", "mayo", "chili sauce"];

var chocolateBananaSundae = ["bananas", "vanilla ice cream", "chocolate sauce", "shredded coconut"];

var cookbook = [noodlesWithChicken, bakedPotatoWithBroccoli, hamPineapplePitaPizza, shrimpOliveSalad, chocolateBananaSundae];

var vegetarians = ["chicken", "ham", "shrimp"];
var veganItems = ["chicken", "ham", "shrimp", "mozzarella", "sour cream", "mayo", "vanilla ice cream"];

cookbook.forEach(function(item){
  var hasMeat = vegetarians.some(item.includes.bind(item));
  console.log(item, hasMeat ? "is not vegetarian" : "is vegetarian");
});
```